# method overriding, embedding and pointer in golang. Can not assign embedded variable

Tags: go, inheritance, overriding, embedding

In go code, there is a method to say:

```
init() {
   service = &Service {
      updater: updaterVariable
   } 
}
```

updater field has type of `*lib.Updater`

I am trying to override one method of `lib.Updater` and pass it to `&Service` in init method (as above).

What I am doing is:

```
type ModifiedUpdater struct {
  lib.Updater
}

//overridden method
func (f *ModifiedUpdater) Update(...) { 
  //implementation
}
```

When I initialize the modified updater and try to pass to Service, I am getting something similar to this `"Cannot use variable of *ModifiedUpdater as *Updater"`

The way I am trying to assign:

```
init() {
   modifiedUpd := &ModifiedUpdater{*lib.Updater{conn}}
   service = &Service {
      updater: modifiedUpd
   } 
}
```

How can I fix it or what approach should I take?
Thank you.

Comment: Without the definition of `Service` this cannot be answered. Note that there is **no** inheritance in Go and you **cannot** override methods.

Answer (score 2):

In Go, we do not have inheritance and you can not override methods of structs. To achieve polymorphism you have Interfaces, in your case you should define some

```
type Updater interface {
   Update(...)
}
```

then implement this method in some struct

```
type somestruct struct {
}

func (ss somestruct) Update(...) {
    //do some work
}
```

and finally, you can use this struct in your init() function

```
init() {
  service = &Service {
     updater: somestruct{}
  } 
}
```

your Service should look like this:

```
type Service struct {
     Updater updater
}
```